# Change dialog background color of a spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-spinner, android-dialog

I want to change the color of the dialog spinner. In Android 4.0.4 I use the dropdown mode, but in 2.2 we don't have this option, it's only dialog. So I need to change the color of dialog background.

I picture of my spinner and the dialog:

[image: Dialog and Spinner]

How you can see, the dialog it's ever white.

Comment: you need to make custom dialog like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289661/custom-height-and-width-in-custom-inflate-alertdialog-layout-android/13289912#13289912  and then take button and call dialog.

Comment: you want to change the color of text ? that is displayed in spinner dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize the Spinner in order to get what you are expecting.
Try [this](http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html) and also [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/)

Comment: I think it's easier to use the Sherlock IcsSpinner to get what I want then.